# TheIntern set up and configuration

Tags: user-interface, coded-ui-tests, intern, gui-testing

I'm trying to get theIntern up and running on a project, I've managed to get Webdriver.io running but need to demo theIntern for web automation. But I can't seem to get the set up right.

I'm using Node and NPM
The Intern dependency is outlined in my package.JSON file 
I've ran an Npm install - and all is ok there.
I have a test file

And selenium standalone is running but I can't seem to get it to work, any suggestions or steps I'm missing would be great thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intern includes support for everything you need to do WebDriver tests, including a Selenium manager and its own WebDriver library. (Note that you will need Java installed to run Selenium, but it sounds like you've already taken care of that.)

To run WebDriver tests, you'll want to write [functional tests](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#writing-functional-test). A functional test will call methods on "remote" (`this.remote`), which is an object implementing a WebDriver API, and return the result.

To actually run the functional tests, use `node_modules/.bin/intern-runner`, or `intern run -w` if you've installed intern-cli. In your Intern config, set the [`tunnel`](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#option-tunnel) property to 'SeleniumTunnel' to let Intern download and manage Selenium, or to 'NullTunnel' to use your own running instance of Selenium.